# Notationally, what is the difference between $\Pr(X = x)$ and $P(X = x)$? When should I use each?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, notation

I'm talking specifically about probability theory. I was reading some stuff about probabilistic graphical models, and they kept switching the notation in this book, but I couldn't discern the difference by context.

One possible hypothesis is that they are subtly different, e.g., $P$ is a probability measure, while $\Pr$ is an unnormalized probability measure (or something; I really have no idea).

Comment: If there's a difference, your book should mention it.  Did you look at the beginning of the book?

Comment: Well, the notational difference is that one has an $r$ and the other doesn't ...

Comment: I would guess sloppy writing, or at best, poor choice of symbols.

Comment: @Graphth, sure did! They didn't mention the difference.

Comment: Which book is that?

Comment: Are you still interested in the answer to this question?

Comment: I am; to answer @Didier's question, it was a probability book I got from my university's math library. I returned it, but I tend to check a lot of them out at once until I understand what I'm doing, so I've forgotten which one precisely. I apologize for not replying.

Comment: When we have a huge equation having variables named p ..... Then writing Pr(.) instead of P(.) would make it more visible, I think. And it cuts off the blunder of treating P as a variable

Answer (score 2):

In general, $Pr(.)$ is used for the probability of an event whereas $p(.)$ is used as a probability measure.

That said, notation in statistics is pretty diverse (also known as a giant mess if you're a student), so always check the book you're reading.